# Auto start specific kernel using grub after a PXE boot

Tags: boot, grub, pxe, fog

I've been working on getting a ipcop installation to work by PXE booting it from a FOG PXE server. When booting, it automatically switches to a grub commandline without booting into the ipcop installation on-disk.

I've figured out what commands to use to manually boot the OS but i need this to boot automatically.

I currently use these grub commands to boot the OS:

```
root (hd1,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.4-3 root=/dev/disk/by-label/root ro mode=normal panic=10 loglevel=4
initrd /boot/ipcoprd-3.4-3.img
```

But now i have to fill these in manually every time I boot. How can I get grub to automatically use these settings?

I haven't been able to find anything useful on the internet yet.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by changing the hardcoded "hd0" for the FOG server grub loader to "hd1". You can find this in the /var/www/fog/lib/fog/BootMenu.class.php

Search for the line that sets the BootExit style.